# Ionic/Angular5 app not rendering correctly on one phone

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 4.4.0 / Angular 5.0.1 app which displays angular variables on a page via expressions {{}}. It does so correctly on a MotoG5/Android 7.0 but it doesn't on a huawei ALE-L23/Android 5.0.1. It doesn't even show the static labels, only a part of the view which is a canvas graph and the rest is white space. Although if we tap around the white space we can see the ion-select pop up and the options.

I've researched for a similar case with no luck.

I'd like to know if someone has faced a similar issue and how you solved it, or if someone can identify what is wrong please.

Here's the code for the View:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      {{ 'GRADES.TITLE' | translate }}
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding id="page3">

    <h1 id="calificaciones-heading1" style="color:#000000;" text-center>
      {{calificacionesAlumno.nombre}}
    </h1>
    <h4 text-center>{{calificacionesAlumno.escuela}}</h4>
    <p text-center>{{ 'GRADES.GRADE-GROUP' | translate }} - {{calificacionesAlumno.gradoGrupo}}</p>
    <p text-center>Periodo: {{calificacionesAlumno.periodo}}</p>
    <ion-list id="calificaciones-list4">
      <ion-item id="calificaciones-select2">
        <ion-label>
          {{ 'GRADES.SELECT-MONTH' | translate }}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-select name="" (ionChange)="obtenerCalificacionesPorPeriodo($event)" interface="popover">
          <ion-option (ngModel)="periodoFiltro" *ngFor="let periodo of periodos" value="{{periodo}}">
            {{periodo}}
          </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-card >
      <ion-card-header>
        {{ 'GRADES.GRAPH-TITLE' | translate }}
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        <canvas #grafCalificaciones></canvas>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-list id="calificaciones-list7">
      <ion-item color="none" id="calificaciones-list-item5" *ngFor="let calificacion of calificacionesAlumno.calificaciones">
        <h2>
          {{calificacion.materia}}
        </h2>
        <h3>
          {{calificacion.calificacion}}
        </h3>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and here are the dependencies package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.4.2",
    "@ionic-native/push": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "9.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4",
    "chart.js": "2.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "1.7.4",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.3.0",
    "firebase": "4.6.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "1.10.5",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-replace": "0.6.1",
    "gulp-zip": "4.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "1.0.1",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.1234"
      },
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "1234"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "1234",
        "APP_NAME": "appName"
      }
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed the template to this predefined one from ionic and it worked. https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-advanced-social

The reason I believe of why it worked on one phone and not on the other, is that maybe the webview's are different and its rendering engine could be different. We now see the importance of testing on different phones!

Answer (score 0):

Replace {{expressions}} with hard coded stuff and see if the problem is really about angular not rendering the variable values or is a css issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've placed hardcoded values and they're still not showing. By css do you mean there could be something hidden? as you can see on most of the elements, I'm not applying any custom css other than the provided by ionic...

Comment: I've also tried changing from the {{expressions}} to this [innerHtml]="variable" and the same issue

Comment: So if you put some hard coded text instead and it's not showing, that would suggest that a for example the text and the background are of the same color and therefore not visibile. Or a parent element with an *ngIf="false" that is hiding a region of your html. In either cases, you need to inspect the element and see if the content (hard coded text) is present in your html document. if it's there, problem is your css. if not, problem is with your template

Comment: I approached it the way you told me, and I found out it was an ionic components issue in how I was using it, so I changed the whole template and it did the job. Basically I was using two ion-lists on the same page which kind of messes up the whole thing